# How to evaluate this integral $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{t^{2}}{2s^{2}} e^{-(t+ \frac{t^{2}}{2s^{2}} )} dt$

Tags: integration, exponential-function, improper-integrals

If the question was $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-(t+ \frac{t^{2}}{2s^{2}} )} dt$, I'd have gone with completing the square of $(t+ \frac{t^{2}}{2s^{2}} )$ and using the normal density trick, but I am stumped with the additional factor. Integration by parts doesn't work either. Please help.

Comment: Tried Feynman's integral trick

Comment: Which is differentiating under the integral sign, I assume. I will look into it. Thank you, @Ken.

Comment: If you complete the square and do a linear substitution, you get an integral looking like $\int_{-\infty}^\infty(At^2+Bt+C)e^{-t^2/s^2}\,dt$. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2/s^2}\,dt$ is the usual probability integral and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty te^{-t^2/s^2}\,dt=0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2e^{-t^2/s^2}\,dt$ comes from the variance of a normal RV.

Comment: @AnginaSeng, That worked! Thank you so much! Please post it as an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
I &= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{t^{2}}{2s^{2}} e^{-(t+ \frac{t^{2}}{2s^{2}} )} dt
= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{t^{2}}{2s^{2}} e^{-\frac1{2s^2}(t+ s^2 )^2 +\frac12s^2}dt\\
& \overset{x=t+s^2}=\frac{e^{\frac{s^2}{2}}}{2s^2} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (x-s^2)^2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}} dx
= \frac{e^{\frac{s^2}{2}}}{2s^2} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (x^2+s^4)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}} dx
\end{align}

Let $a=\frac1{2s^2}$ and use
$$J(a)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-ax^2}dx= \sqrt{\frac\pi a},\>\>\>\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x^2e^{-ax^2}dx=-J’(a) = \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2a^{3/2}}$$
to obtain

$$I=  \frac{e^{\frac{s^2}{2}}}{2s^2} 
\left( \sqrt{2\pi}s^3 + \sqrt{2\pi} s^5\right)=\sqrt{\frac\pi2} e^{\frac{s^2}{2}}s(1+s^2)
$$